# merge multiple lines into single line by value of column

Tags: python, perl, split

I have a tab-delimited text file that is very large. Many lines in the file have the same value for one of the columns in the file. I want to put them into same line. For example:

```
a foo
a bar
a foo2
b bar
c bar2
```

After run the script it should become:

```
a foo;bar;foo2
b bar
c bar2
```

how can I do this in either a shell script or in Python?

thanks.

Comment: Are the similar lines sequential? (All the A lines come before the B lines, B before C, etc) If so, this is fairly trivial. If not, it's slightly less trivial. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk you can try this

```
{   a[$1] = a[$1] ";" $2 }
END { for (item in a ) print item, a[item] }
```

So if you save this awk script in a file called awkf.awk and if your input file is ifile.txt, run the script

```
awk -f awkf.awk ifile.txt | sed 's/ ;/ /'
```

The sed script is to remove out the leading ;

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = defaultdict(list)
for line in open('sourcefile'):
    key, val = line.split('\t')
    items[key].append(val)

result = open('result', 'w')
for k in sorted(items):
    result.write('%s\t%s\n' % (k, ';'.join(items[k])))
result.close()
```

not tested

Comment: what is the "from collections import defaultdict" and "items = defaultdict(list)" ?

Comment: @Jianguo : "defaultdict" is not a builtin type so you have to import it, and it is in "collections". http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 1):

Tested with Python 2.7:

```
import csv

data = {}

reader = csv.DictReader(open('infile','r'),fieldnames=['key','value'],delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    if row['key'] in data:
        data[row['key']].append(row['value'])
    else:
        data[row['key']] = [row['value']]

writer = open('outfile','w')
for key in data:
    writer.write(key + '\t' + ';'.join(data[key]) + '\n')
writer.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transform.py", line 16, in <module>
    writer.write(key+'\t'+string.join(data[key],';')+'\n')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 318, in join
    return sep.join(words)

Comment: I tested this in Python 2.6 as well without error. I did glean from the error message that I could simplify the code `string.join(data[key],';')` to `';'.join(data[key])`

Comment: @Jianguo As for your error, does the code as listed produce this error? I created infile from a paste of the source data as you listed in your question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transform.py", line 18, in <module>
    writer.write(key+'\t'+ ';'.join(data[key])+'\n')
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

Comment: @Jianguo I notice from the error message that you may be running on Linux so I tested that as well using Python 2.4 and 2.6. Still no error for me. Since your error number is on line 18 and the test code is only 15 lines long, I would need to see more code to debug this error. What are the contents of the key and data objects prior to this line?

Answer (score 0):

```
def compress(infilepath, outfilepath):
    input = open(infilepath, 'r')
    output = open(outfilepath, 'w')
    prev_index = None

    for line in input:
        index, val = line.split('\t')
        if index == prev_index:
            output.write(";%s" %val)
        else:
            output.write("\n%s %s" %(index, val))
    input.close()
    output.close()
```

Untested, but should work. Please leave a comment if there are any concerns

Comment: "infilepath" and "outfilepath" should be inputfile and outputfile or the directory?

Comment: They are strings which are the paths to the input file and the output file, resp.

Comment: I just made an edit that should make the code more memory efficient

Comment: File "./transform.py", line 7
    def compress("/home/jianguo/software/tanghaibao-goatools-bfce032/data" "/home/jianguo/software/tanghaibao-goatools-bfce032/data"):
                                                                         ^

Answer (score 0):

A Perl way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh, '<', 'path/to/file' or die "unable to open file:$!";
my %res;
while(<$fh>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split;
    push @{$res{$k}}, $v;
}
print Dumper \%res;
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
      'c' => [
               'bar2'
             ],
      'a' => [
               'foo',
               'bar',
               'foo2'
             ],
      'b' => [
               'bar'
             ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# for demo only
*ARGV = *DATA;

my %record;
my @order;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my($key,$combine) = split;

  push @order, $key unless exists $record{$key};
  push @{ $record{$key} }, $combine;
}

print $_, "\t", join(";", @{ $record{$_} }), "\n" for @order;

__DATA__
a foo
a bar
a foo2
b bar
c bar2
```

Output (with tabs converted to spaces because Stack Overflow breaks the output):

```
a       foo;bar;foo2
b       bar
c       bar2
```